# Polymorphism in Relationship Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SqlAchemy Model that have a relationship with a Single Table Inheritance, like this:

```
@Schema(nested=['sensor', 'mad_version', 'serial_interface'], fields=('sensor',))
class Mad(sql.Model):
    #columns...
    serial_interface = relationship(SerialInterface, uselist=False, cascade="all, delete-orphan")

@Schema(nested=['serial_protocol'])
class SerialInterface(sql.Model, InheritanceModel):
    id = sql.Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    transmission_rate = sql.Column(types.Integer)

    mad_id = sql.Column(types.Integer, sql.ForeignKey('mad.id'))
    serial_protocol = sql.relationship(SerialProtocol, uselist=False, cascade="all, delete-orphan")

class RS485(SerialInterface):
    parity = sql.Column(EnumSmart(Parity))
    data_bits = sql.Column(types.Integer)
    stop_bits = sql.Column(types.Integer)

    polymorphic_identity = SerialTypes.RS485.name

class Ethernet(SerialInterface):
    #Others Columns
```

My doubt is How i can Query Mad Model and returning Child attribute? Because now it only return  SerialInterface if his own attributes(without child attributes). I saw in documentation that i can use `with_polymorphic` in polimorfism, but this polimorfism is inside a relationship, have some way to overwrite relationship query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution adding `'with_polymorphic': '*'` in  `__mapper_args__` like this:

```
@declared_attr
def __mapper_args__(cls):
   return {
      'polymorphic_identity': cls.__name__,
      'polymorphic_on': cls.type,
      'with_polymorphic': '*'
   }
```